# What SQL Query to do a simple find and replace

Tags: mysql, query, sql, customization

Whenever I create a new website I first create a staging site on a subdomain like "stage.domain-name.com".

After everything works correctly I export the database, open it in notepad++ and do a find/replace for "subdomain.domain-name.com" and replace it with "domain-name.com"... finally I import it into a new database for the live site.

My question is... what SQL query would I need to run if I just wanted to do this simple find/replace on the entire database using phpmyadmin?

-CH

Comment: If you're not familiar with queries try the Search and Replace plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/

Comment: Why not use WordPress functionality to update the URL?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress details everything

Comment: There is a plugin for this. It allows comfortable use of the backend and also replaces the URL in the post-content and some other fields, if you want to: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Comment: doing this with an SQL query will corrupt any serialized PHP values stored in the database, breaking the site if the new URL is a different length from the old URL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The table where your URL is saved is wp_options. You should do an update on the columns that use the URL for your site:

```
UPDATE TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "new domain" WHERE option_name = "siteurl"
UPDATE TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "new domain" WHERE option_name = "home"
```

I might be missing some value, but whenever you do this find/replace process again, you can notice the values and tables that should be updated and add them to this script.

WordPress Codex has a nice guide on how to change a site URL, maybe that's even handier for you: [Changing the Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: is there not a way to do a find/replace on the entire database? In other words... I noticed for example that I need to replace the URLs in a bunch of different locations including the media library.... If there was a find/replace for the entire database essentially for every field then this would solve the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Check out that new link I added on the answer. I think that would be the way to go.

Comment: This will not work for serialized data. It might completely break some theme configuration.

Answer (score 42):

Best to do options, posts, post content and post meta:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Also see [Searching Data using phpMyAdmin and MySQL | Packt Publishing.](http://www.packtpub.com/article/searching-data-using-phpmyadmin-and-mysql) And [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good WP plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.

**Update 6/16/2015:** Using the tool linked in the next sentence is much better, as a *simple find/replace as above in a database dump will break serialized data.* See [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool.](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) This way, you don't break serialized data and won't need to run RegEx on post content, as the interconnect script changes URLs everywhere. I use that tool all the time to migrate sites to different domains, or to simply do a global change from http to https to force SSL without plugins and change all URLs in content to prevent insecure element errors.

**Edit 9/02/21**
WP CLI is also a great tool, and it correctly handles serialized data. See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: Don't ever change the guid - even if going to a new domain. It's used to uniquely ID the post as the ID can change if the posts are being exported/imported into a new database. For one thing, RSS readers will use the GUID to tell if a particular article has been read or not. Changing the guid will effectively republish all your articles.

Comment: @taylordewey said: "Don't ever change the guid..." Rubbish.

Comment: @songdogtech Care to explain *why* it is rubbish?

Comment: If you're changing domains, you simply don't have a choice and have to change GUIDs. Fallout from RSS readers is a minimal price to pay.

Comment: Why would one _have_ to change the GUID?

Comment: Despite GUID's containing a url, they aren't used to create links (for example in menu's) when referencing posts. And so _not_ changing them is perfectly acceptable

Comment: This will not work for serialized data. It might completely break some theme configuration. Indeed use a tool such as Interconnect/IT’s.

Answer (score 10):

This is a great drop-in script that I use and it works beautifully with the serialized arrays that WP uses to store options.  Just make sure to delete it from your remote server when you're done because it's a HUGE security risk.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: I don't know why I was -1'd.  This script is much better than a SQL statement.  Feedback please?

Comment: a tool that people who dont know sql can use, is upsetting to those who write in sql

Answer (score 9):

For this I use [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) because I find it the easiest and it takes care of serialized data.

`wp search-replace 'http://example.dev' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid`

There is also an option that writes your changes into an SQL file instead of manipulating the actual database:

`wp search-replace foo bar --export=database.sql`

Comment: by far the most robust and fastest solution. wp-cli saves the day once again

Answer (score 2):

you do not have to do this , you can use relative paths.

when you are linking something instead of subdomain.soemthing.com/image.jpg - use /image.jpg for example

like this you won't face the problem in the first place.

otherwise for a mysql update statement you can use

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

Comment: Thanks... yeah I will do that next time. The SQL statement does a find replacement on the entire database (including all tables)?

Comment: @NetConstructor.com The SQL statement mireille gave you above is the generic MySQL command for replacing a string in a specific field in a specific table. If you tried running this statement exactly as it was written, it wouldn't work. For this command to work, you'd need to change the TABLE_NAME & FIELD_NAME to a real field and table used by WordPress.

Comment: Note also that even if you desire to use relative paths, lots of parts of wordpress tend to auto-insert full paths. To really get this working a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/root-relative-urls/ is very, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

To change the wordpress domain what we often need, may be to make the site live from localhost: This is a complete list of update queries:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_links SET link_image = replace(link_image, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

/*UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl' OR option_name = 'widget_text' OR option_name = 'dashboard_widget_options';*/
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

- We have to also add other tables which are not default with WP if necessary.

**UPDATE:** [Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) version 3.1.0 is a user-friendly, front-end tool for developers, that allows you to carry out database wide search/replace actions, that don't damage PHP serialized strings or objects.

Comment: This will not work for serialized data. It might completely break theme configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you don't have to use a SQL query just some adjustments in wp_config and functions.php file in your theme. Check out this topic in Wordpress Codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: This isn't correct. WordPress unfortunately stores some URL in the database as text.